# Java TestPassByvalue

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on this code for school but it tells me to modify the main method so after the call to the swap method the actual values of num1 and num2 are swapped in main and show this in the output.  Do not simply change the order of the two numbers in a print or println statement, you must include the swap code in the main method.Your output will have one additional line that shows the values of the two numbers in main after they are swapped.  See new output line below in blue text. How could I do this?

my code is below

```
public class TestPassByValue {
/** Main method */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declare and initialize variables
    int num1 = 1;
    int num2 = 2;

    System.out.println("Before invoking the swap method, num1 is " + num1 + " and num2 is " + num2);

    // invoke the swap method to attempt to swap two variables
    swap(num1, num2);

    System.out.println("After invoking the swap method, num1 is " + num1 + " and num2 is " + num2);
}

/** Swap two variables */
public static void swap(int n1, int n2) {
    System.out.println("\tInside the swap method");
    System.out.println("\t\tBefore swapping, n1 is " + n1 + " and n2 is " + n2);

    // Swap n1 with n2
    int temp = n1;
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = temp;

    System.out.println("\t\tAfter swapping, n1 is " + n1 + " and n2 is " + n2);
}
```

}

Comment: This is pretty unclear. What is the "line below in blue text" you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Your question's text heading in not clear, But if you want to second print statement inside main method to print to print swapped values.

"System.out.println("After invoking the swap method, num1 is " + num1 + " and num2 is " + num2);"

Then you will have to create a new Class with int value as field inside the class. And use this object instead of using primitive int variable num1 and num2. 
eg

```
class MyInteger{
    int i;

    MyInteger(int i){
        this.i = i;
    }
```

....

```
}
```

If you don't want this then you code works fine by printing same value num1 =1 and num2 = 2 in second print statement inside main.